# Move all drawn pixels in Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing

Once I have drawn all I need in a `Canvas`, is there a way to move it all ? Like move it all 10 pixels down ? I search though the [functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) and [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=java+canvas+move+pixels) but I saw nothing interesting.

A lot of things are drawn so recalibrating all the app is kinda hard to do. Any ideas to do this ? I am working in Android, but I don't think it matters.

Maybe I could get the pixels and copy them 1 by 1, but I feel it would be so slow.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**: For those who have the same question. If you want to use `translate()` this is how it works. If you set `translate(x, y)`, when you draw something it will be automatically shiffted by those (x & y) values.

For example: if you execute the following:

```
canvas.translate(5, 10);
```

And then draw a line:

```
canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20).
```

The line will be printed from [5,10] to [25, 30]. So everything you draw is moved automatically, [5, 10] becomes [0, 0]. You can also `canvas.translate(-5, -10)` to put it back like it was (or reset it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your question right, you could use the `canvas.translate()` function. You could execute this in your `onDraw()` method of your Canvas. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) is the documentation for the function (scroll to the very bottom of the page). Hope it helps!

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how it works but it did. Thank you so much!